# Jacobian transformation

Tags: probability, multivariate-analysis

Suppose $J_1 $ be the Jacobian for transforming $(x_1,x_2,...,x_n) \to (y_1,y_2,...,y_n) $ and let $J_2 $ be the Jacobian for transforming $(y_1,y_2,...,y_n) \to (x_1,x_2,..,x_n) $ then prove that $J_1=\frac{1}{J_2} $ .

Basically I can prove this for single variable but how to do for n variables?

Comment: How did you prove it for $n=1$?  Some proof methods generalize; for instance, consider the round trip transformation from $x$ to $y$ back to $x:$ what is its Jacobian and how is it related to $J_1$ and $J_2$?

Comment: Is this a homework or an exam question? If so, you should use the `self-study` tag.

Comment: For n =1 ,Suppose $f:U\rightarrow V, g:V\rightarrow U$ are differentiable where $U,V\subset {\bf R}$ are open subsets and that $f,g$ are inverses.
Also suppose $a\in U, b\in V, f(a)=b$. Differentiating $gf(x)=x$ in $x=a$ gives $g'(b)f'(a)=I$. Taking determinants gives $J_g(b) J_f(a)=1$.